# Starting bounty on others question

Tags: support, bounty

I am facing some problem with my Ubuntu and solving those problem is very much important for me. After searching on Ask Ubuntu, I found some similar questions [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/457983/how-can-i-get-my-webcam-to-work-with-ubuntu-14-04)  and [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/461657/integrated-webcam-not-detected-after-update-to-14-04) with little  response.

Now what should I do. Should I start a bounty on the existing question  on should I ask a new question and then start bounty on my own question.

Comment: This depends, it would help if we knew which questions you are looking at so we can also give them a look and help out. Please edit your question and add in what you're looking at.

Comment: ok. I have edited my post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case only if you have the exact model of camera that they have then I would edit/bounty one of them, if not, start a new question to the specific model.